# Dataframe with date index outputting series or value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One is created with yfinance and looks likes this:

[image]

The second one is created using alpha_vantage and looks like this:
[image]

On the first dataframe, I can just call;

```
day = "2012-12-14" 
print(h['Close'][day])
```

and it will output me a double value.

for the second dataframe, it returns me a series:

```
2020-12-14    639.83
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

The only difference I can see is that the order is reversed. How can I adapt the second dataframe so that it responds like the first?

Comment: Would be better if you could paste a sample of both dataframes as text with expected output.

Comment: Do you need `print(h.loc[day, 'Close'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... reversing the rows solved this... no idea why though.

```
data = data.iloc[::-1]
```